# Проблема с описанием типа event(react)

Tags: reactjs, события, типизация

Динамическая ленивая подгрузка данных...всё работает ...вот проблема с типизацией...в частности с описанием event..событие то на window

```
      const scrollHandler = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      e.target.documentElement.scrollHeight - (
        window.scrollY + window.innerHeight
      ) < 50
    ) {
      setIsFetching(true);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onscroll = scrollHandler;
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена:

```
const scrollHandler = (e: Event) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      (e.target as Document).documentElement.scrollHeight - (
        window.scrollY + window.innerHeight
      ) < 50
    ) {
      setIsFetching(true);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
  });
```